# Why java Locale is final?

Tags: java, internationalization, locale

I want to use Java Locale for internationalization with Russian language, but Locale has just a small number of constants defined and Russian is not one of them. What kind of work around should I use?

```
public final class Locale implements Cloneable, Serializable {

/** Useful constant for language.
 */
static public final Locale ENGLISH = createConstant("en", "");
```

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza what is that? I have no idea

Comment: I usually pick one answer as acceptable or comment on it. Should I accept or reject every answer?

Comment: You should accept only 1 answer in the question. The answer must be *the best* for you or the one that helped you to get to *your* solution. If no answer helps you, then you can still wait for a good answer in that question.

Comment: I have checked all my questions. If there are answers I have I always picked one of them. If no answers then no picking.

Comment: You should click the check next to the answer. It would show a green check after that.

Comment: Do it in all your questions as well (if they had a good answer,of course).

Comment: The only question I have is, why do you want to **hardcode** a Locale? Because in i18n-compliant application there is only one constant you may want to use (`Locale.ROOT`). Apart from that you should **detect** a Locale rather than force one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constants are there just for convenience.

The [Locale class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) uses ISO 3166 standard for country codes and ISO 639 for language codes.

For the Russian language in the Russian Federation, the following call should be sufficient:

```
Locale ru_loc = new Locale("ru", "RU");
```

Answer (score 1):

check this out the iso-639 code for russian 
http://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/IG/ert/iso639.htm

can you try using this while creating Locale.

```
public Locale(String language, String country)
```

Construct a locale from language, country. NOTE: ISO 639 is not a stable standard; some of the language codes it defines (specifically iw, ji, and in) have changed. This constructor accepts both the old codes (iw, ji, and in) and the new codes (he, yi, and id), but all other API on Locale will return only the OLD codes.  (copied from javadoc)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#Locale%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: yes, it doesn't answer your question but can solve your problem that you want to support the Russian lang.

Answer (score 0):

Here is tutorial how to create Locale.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html